# Is this a Homeomorphism in Topology?

Tags: general-topology

I want to show a connection between Genotype and Phenotype Spaces, but I need a Homeomorphism from R^1 to R^3 so I can use Binary sequence of funcitons that can map to 3-space. The only problem is I don't remember if R^1 is Homeomorphic to R^3. Sooo.... my question is R^1 homeomorphic to R^3 and can I have a binary map go and map to 3-space?

Comment: No, $\mathbb{R}^1$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. What do you need homeomorphism for?

Comment: I mostly wanted a Homeomorphism for setting up a binary sequence of functions that uniformly converge to a binary continuous function. That continuous function f might be my bijection between R and R^3. But if it just can't exist then there is no point to pursue this endeavor anymore. I also feel like I'm making leap form binary sequence of functions converging uniformly to a continuous function in R^3.

Answer (score 1):

If there were a homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then there would also be a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{x \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \setminus \{\phi(x)\}$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ given by the restriction of $\phi$ to that subspace, but this cannot exist because the former is connected whereas the latter is not ([continuous maps preserve connectedness](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Connected_Space_is_Connected)).  So $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ cannot be homeomorphic.

As path-connectedness is also preserved under continuous maps, you can also get this result by noting that there exists connected-but-not-path-connected sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but not in $\mathbb{R}$ (cf. the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve)).

In greater generality, $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ are not homeomorphic whenever $n \neq m$, but showing this requires more sophisticated machinery.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful insight. I just honestly thought there would be a nice function that worked I guess not.

Comment: Glad I could help :)  Best of luck